# Filtering json records procured from a file using asp.net webapi

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am reading the values from a json file  via my api. How do i filter the records based on id?

Please find the code below.

```
[HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
        {
            var productsjson = File.ReadAllText(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/products.json"));


            var response = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Content = new StringContent(productsjson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            return response;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the contents / structure of the json it's hard to answer. Ideally you should parse the productsjson string into a json object using Newtonsoft or something comparable. From there you can filter the contents of the object / array before returning it to the client